# CGDB - cannot add breakponts

Tags: c++, gdb, breakpoints

*Sometimes* I cannot add breakpoints using (c)gdb.

I can add them after first or second run of the program, but then when I try to set any more (either in library or application source code) (either through `CGDB` Window or `gdb` command line) I'm greet with following information:

`Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffeb480d10`

*Sometimes* everything works great and without any problems.

```
System: SLES 11 SP3 (3.0.76-0.11)
  CGDB: 0.6.7
   GDB: 7.5.1-0.7.29
```

Running as root/as regular user makes no difference in behavior. Should I provide more details - just say. I have been using this configuration for quite long time now and didn't encounter this (any) problem earlier.

Comment: This can have a lot of reasons: you try to access a address which is not existing, which you have no rights to write or you simply trashed your stack somewhere. If you are not doing some mystery like protecting some pages of your program or other stuff, it should work. If you corrupt your stackframe and can't find the problem: Try to use valgrind first and come back to gdb after fixing that.

Comment: @Klaus You read me wrong - the problem isn't memory access or any problem with my program itself. The problem is that GDB can't make breakpoint.

Comment: One method to set a brakepoint is to write a special instruction into the programm memory ( maybe a trap or soft irq or what else, depending on OS and CPU ). But if gdb could not access the program memory, this message appears. And why gdb tries to write maybe on the wrong address or could not access the correct address was mentioned above.

Comment: I am aware of such an issue when working with core dumps. However, it was first time it happend with live execution. What's more strange - I wanted to collect stack trace and memory of faulty gdb session to add to this question but after posting it issue ceased to reproduce. And as I said corruption is out of question - checked with efence and valgrind very carefully. Thanks for the suggestion of breakpoints set directly by debugged software -  I will do some research on the matter.

Comment: I decided to revisit this question. Some memory corruptions happen to render GDB not working. It can result in being unable to place a breakpoint, GDB pretty printer giving strange output and other problems.